# Doctest NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE does not work

Tags: python, doctest

```
Failed example:
    p.parse_name('Adams, Michael') 
    # doctest: +NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE
Expected:
    {'first_name': 'Michael', 'last_name': 'Adams','initials': 'MA'}
Got:
    {'first_name': 'Michael', 'last_name': 'Adams', 'initials': 'MA'}
```

The docstring is -

```
>>> p.parse_name('Adams, Michael') 
... # doctest: +NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE
{'first_name': 'Michael', 'last_name': 'Adams','initials': 'MA'}
```

Comment: Why not add a space after `s',`?

Comment: Then what is the use of +NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html#doctest.NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE):

> When specified, all *sequences of whitespace* (blanks and newlines) are treated as equal. Any sequence of whitespace within the expected output will match any sequence of whitespace within the actual output

`','` contains no sequence of whitespace, so is not treated as equal to `', '`.

---

You might want to read the [warnings section](http://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html#warnings) of the docs:

> Python doesn’t guarantee that the key-value pairs will be printed in
>   any particular order, so a test like
>
> ```
> >>> foo()
> {"Hermione": "hippogryph", "Harry": "broomstick"}
> ```
>
> is vulnerable! One workaround is to do
>
> ```
> >>> foo() == {"Hermione": "hippogryph", "Harry": "broomstick"}
> True
> ```

Comment: For the dict order issue, ``pprint`` is a nice solution also. ``from pprint import pprint as pp; pp(foo())``. ``pprint`` will sort keys and also help having a nice readable display of big structures.